# Hive query passing string as an argument

Tags: hadoop, hive

Here's my hive query in a shell script. what it does is to read one tablename at a time from a text file and run the hive query to insert rows into it.

When I replace 'I' with an integer value say 1, it works fine. Tried few ways to pass 'I' but it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

**Hive Query**

```
for line in $(cat ../hive/ListofTableNames.txt);

do

 eval "hive -e 'SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

 FROM sourcedb.$line

 INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE targetdb.$line

 SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()),**'I'**,*;'"

done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the hive QL in a file let's say myRequest.ql:

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
FROM sourcedb.${hiveconf:tableName}
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE targetdb.${hiveconf:tableName}
SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()),**'I'**,*;'"
```

and then your script will be like:

```
for line in $(cat ../hive/ListofTableNames.txt);

do
    eval "hive --hiveconf tableName=$line -f myRequest.ql"
done
```

Hope that will help

Comment: I get this error - Error occurred executing hive query: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 2:40 cannot recognize input near '*' 'I' '*' in selection target

Comment: could you add the output of `(cat ../hive/ListofTableNames.txt` please?

Comment: After I moved the query to a separate file like you had mentioned, I replaced **'I'** with just 'I' and it worked. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would try

1. Write SQL to a file and use --hivevar option to pass the variables to the HQL 
      hive --hivevar I=BB -f your.hql
2. From the script write sql to tmp file, run hive -f

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the single quote in your query.

```
for line in $(cat ../hive/ListofTableNames.txt);
do
 eval "hive -e 'SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
 FROM sourcedb.$line
 INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE targetdb.$line
 SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()),**\'I\'**,*;'"
done
```

As there is an opening single quote before `SET` operation, so it will take next quote as closing quote. So to avoid such cases, always use escape character.

Another neat option is, to write the query in a seperate file and save as query.ql. And execute it using `-f filename.ql` as suggested by user1314742